# SOAP: Client ip is not allowed to use this service

Tags: python, api, soap, zeep

Im try to collect data from API based on SOAP
Theoretically everything works and code is ready, but when i run it i have an error:

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Client [ip] is not allowed to use this service
```

I search internet for answer, and still don't find it

My whole code:

```
import zeep

wsdl_url = 'https://api.mediaexpert.pl/?q=ws/wsdl/products'
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl_url, service_name='TergProductsDataService')

EAN_Code = '123456'
response = client.service.prodsCMS2USPGet(prodID=zeep.xsd.SkipValue, prodIndex=zeep.xsd.SkipValue, prodEAN=EAN_Code, insiderFlag=zeep.xsd.SkipValue, http200=zeep.xsd.SkipValue)

if response is not None and response.prodData is not None:
    product_info = response.prodData[0]
print('Price: ', product_info.priceBrutto)
```

And i call to that corporation, they dont need password to connect to ther API.

Raw link to API:
https://api.mediaexpert.pl/?q=ws/wsdl/products